# NotificationManager Channel Importance Levels are incorrect

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications, notification-channel

I am playing around with notification channels and noticed that the channel importance levels of the emulator don't fit to the `NotificationManager` constants.

NotificationManager:

```
public static final int IMPORTANCE_MIN = 1;
public static final int IMPORTANCE_LOW = 2;
public static final int IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT = 3;
public static final int IMPORTANCE_HIGH = 4;
public static final int IMPORTANCE_MAX = 5;
```

Emulator:

[image]

I retrieved the importance level the following way:

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationChannel channel2 = manager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_2_ID);
        int importance = channel2.getImportance();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: check the docs https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: Thank you, I just saw it too. That's very confusing.